# heredoc with ldapmodify in bash script

Tags: bash, ldap

I am trying to write a bash script with heredoc with `ldamodify`;

```
/usr/bin/ldapmodify -x -h ldap-master.x-region.COMPANY.com -p 3891 -D "uid=COMPANY-ldap-team-me,ou=ldap users,ou=infrastructure,o=COMPANY.com" -W <<EOF
dn: cn=Jeff Lebowski (dude),ou=people,ou=us,o=COMPANY.com
changetype: modify
replace: nsAccountLock
nsAccountLock: false
EOF
```

Above is how I would enter the command into the terminal. However in a bash script I have a function to get the dn;

```
get_dn () {
    /usr/bin/ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -LLLxh ldap.COMPANY.com:389 -b o=COMPANY.com uid=dude | grep -i "dn:" | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

I then want to expand this into the unlock command in the script via a function call like;

```
unlock_account () {
/usr/bin/ldapmodify -x -h ldap-master.x-region.COMPANY.com -p 3891 -D "uid=svc-ldap-team-$USER,ou=ldap users,ou=infrastructure,o=COMPANY.com" -W
$(get_dn) cat << EOF
changetype: modify
replace: nsAccountLock
nsAccountLock: false
EOF
}
```

However, when I call it, it doesn't expand the EOF heredoc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
unlock_account () {
/usr/bin/ldapmodify -x \
-h ldap-master.x-region.COMPANY.com \
-p 3891 \
-D "uid=svc-ldap-team-$USER,ou=ldap users,ou=infrastructure,o=COMPANY.com" \
-W << EOF
$(get_dn)
changetype: modify
replace: nsAccountLock
nsAccountLock: false
EOF
}
```